# get_categories returning an empty array when it shouldn't

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a file management plugin that uses the category system to create a mock filesystem hierarchy and I'm running into some issues with some code that is responsible for recursively deleting the 'folders' (actually categories). Instead of the code returning all of the child categories of the category to be deleted, it returns an empty array. Any ideas why?

```
    //get all child categories
    $wk_child_categories = get_categories(array('child_of' => $_POST['wk_ID'], 'orderby' => 'term_group'));
    echo " Got the child categories. They are:";
   print_r($wk_child_categories);
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the value of `$_POST['wk_ID']` is what you expect it to be?

Comment: Checked that - all is well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One thing that I can see that might be causing the issue is the lack of the `post` parameter. By default if you don't have a post parameter it will fallback to the standard Wordpress "post" type. If you are using a custom post type it would return an empty array because the query is looking in the wrong spot.

There is also the possibility that the categories are empty. In the arguments for [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) there is a `hide_empty` argument that will default to not return empty categories, try setting that to `0`

Comment: Okay, despite the categories NOT being empty, adding the hide_empty => 0 parameter fixed it. I shouldn't have needed it according to the wordpress codex, where it says with regards to the 'child_of' parameter: "If the parameter is used, the hide_empty parameter is set to false.". Must have been something to do with enabling categories for attachments. Thanks for your help!